# Good practices for uploading images through a restful API

Tags: json, rest, upload, amazon-s3, multipart

I'm using Amazon S3 in my restful service to upload images.
The restful service is being accessed by a iPhone app.
I'm trying to figure what will be the best approach to upload the images.

Option 1: Use a multipart form data to upload the image and also include the JSON itself as another multipart in the HTTP request.

Option 2: a. Upload the image directly to Amazon S3 and get the URL back.
          b. Send a restful request with the JSON including the image URL.

Which approach would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

I go for Option 1 as it is one request. It is better than 2 separate round trips (in Option 2).